# Style first 3 posts differently with a container, then the rest of the posts

Tags: loop

I can style the first three posts differently with no problem.

What I can't figure out, is how to do it and include the first three posts in a single container div (e.g. not a new div for each post).

The output would be something like this: (but obviously this will loop the container, and I don't want that...)

```
<?php
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query(array(
'post_type'=>'post',
));

$i = 1; // counter to style first 3 different

if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $wp_query->the_post(); ?> 

<?php 
    if($i < 4) { // first 3 posts ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="post">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php } else { // not the first 3 posts  ?>

        <div class="differnt-post-style">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Do you want one container to wrap the first three posts or 1 container around each of the first three posts? It sounds like you want your first three posts in a shared container, but I cannot quite tell.

Comment: @Privateer - correct in the first thing you said. I want one container around the first 3 posts, not one around each. Thanks

Comment: you're almost there- open the container before the loop and close the container when `$i` equals 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Milo noted, the final result might look something like the following

```
if ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
        $wp_query->the_post();
        $post_title = get_the_title();

        # On the first pass, write the start of your single container
        if ( 0 == $wp_query->current_post ) {
            echo '<div class="container">';
        }
        echo <<<HTML
<div class="different-post-style">
    {$the_title}
</div>
HTML;

        # On the 3rd pass, close your single container
        if ( 2 == $wp_query->current_post ) {
            echo "\r\n</div>";
        }

    }
    # Close the div if there were 2 or fewer posts
    if ( $wp_query->current_post < 2 ) {
        echo "\r\n</div>";
    }
}
```

Modified as per Milo's comment. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: you can also use `$wp_query->current_post` property in place of your own counter.

Comment: Ahhh, that's it. Thanks a lot to both! @Milo and Privateer